# Filtering DQL query with NOT EXISTS condition using values from ManyToMany association

Tags: php, mysql, doctrine-orm

Sorry to make the first post a question but I don't think I have enough experience yet to offer valuable help. Hope someone is willing to lend a hand with this quandary I've been stuck on.

I'm having trouble writing a conditional DQL clause to filter out entities whose id exists in a pivot table created by a ManyToMany association.

```
class Product
{
    /**
      * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="App\Entity\GroupProduct", fetch="EXTRA_LAZY", inversedBy="products")
      * @ORM\JoinTable(name="product_group_product" )
      */

    private $groupProduct; 
}
```

I cannot use the *product_group_product* pivot table in the DQL query since it's not mapped by a dedicated entity.
Is it possible to write a DQL query which does the same thing as this SQL query:

```
SELECT * FROM product as p WHERE NOT EXISTS (
SELECT 1 FROM product_group_product as gp WHERE gp.product_id = p.id
);
```

I've tried:

```
->andWhere('p NOT MEMBER OF p.groupProduct')
```

But the resulting NOT EXISTS clause in the SQL query contains an index comparison between Product and GroupProduct entity ids which makes it return false:

```
AND NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM product_group_product p1_ 
INNER JOIN group_product g2_ ON p1_.group_product_id = g2_.id 
WHERE p1_.product_id = p0_.id 
-->AND g2_.id IN (p0_.id)<--)
```

Any ideas would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I'm understanding this correctly, I think you can do this with a *left join* instead of a sub-query.

## In SQL

For example, in SQL:

```
select * from product p
left join product_group_product gp on gp.product_id = p.id
where gp.id is null
```

This query should get products that aren't in product_group_product.

It works because a left-join includes all products, even if they don't have product_group_product entries. When products don't have product_group_product entries, those columns will be returned as null. The `where` statement then filters out those products that have their corresponding `product_group_product.id` as null.

One "gotcha" with this if a product does have a product_group_product, but the product_group_product's ID is null, it will also be returned. This isn't an issue if product_group_product.id is non-nullable, as is often the case.

## In DQL

In Doctrine, it's a bit trickier to do queries based off of product_group_product because it is a JoinTable, which doesn't have an entity and is abstracted away by Doctrine.

Instead, you should be able to use the same kind of left join, except using the relationship defined with your `GroupProduct` entity:

```
$query = $em->createQuery('SELECT p FROM App\Entity\Product p LEFT JOIN p.groupProduct gp where gp is NULL');
```

Comment: Thanks Eric, and welcome to StackOverflow. The SQL example is helpful, though you might enhance your answer with an example DQL. Could it be similar to this answer? https://stackoverflow.com/a/22636157/1308685

Comment: Hi Jeremy - thanks for the feedback! I totally agree with you - some DQL should help. I'll add a DQL example and some more details as soon as I have some spare time today. Thanks again!

Comment: Thank you for the response. The sql query you provided does indeed yield the intended result but I am unable to figure out how to convert it to dql. The problem is how to access fields in the *product_group_product* pivot table. Any thoughts?

Comment: Hi @JonB - that's great to hear the SQL is working! I've updated the answer with a DQL equivalent. Please let us know if it works for you.

Comment: Hi @Eric, sorry for the delayed reply. I did try that already but unfortunately the resulting sql doesn't apply the null condition to the product_id column in _product_group_product_ . There are actually 2 left joins in the resulting query: LEFT JOIN product_group_product p2_ ON p.id = p2_.product_id LEFT JOIN group_product g1_ ON g1_.id = p2_.group_product_id AND **(g1_.id IS NULL)**.....The null condition gets applied to the group_product table which is the inverse-side of the ManyToMany association. I'm really at odds as to how this can be done...

Comment: I read this in the Doctrine ORM documentation:
_Why are many-to-many associations less common? Because frequently you want to associate additional attributes with an association, in which case you introduce an association class. Consequently, the direct many-to-many association disappears and is replaced by one-to-many/many-to-one associations between the 3 participating classes._ Any thoughts as to how one might implement this and if it would help in this case?

Comment: Hi @JonB - I'm a bit confused now. Doesn't this achieve the desired results? Keep in mind they are left-joins, so a Product that isn't in the join table product_group_product also won't have a group product in the results.

Comment: @Eric. Bingo! I figured out my mistake. I was writing the query with QueryBuilder and had the WHERE gp IS NULL condition within the ->leftJoin() option rather than a separate ->andWhere() clause. Thanks for your help Eric. Much appreciated!

Comment: @JonB Ah that makes sense. Happy to help, and welcome to Stack Overflow! If you feel this answer solved your issue, please mark it as "accepted" by clicking the check mark. Cheers!